# Comparing date type column with a timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sysdate

I have a table say demo with three columns

```
create table demo(demo_id number,
                  created_date date,
                  mod_date systimestamp(6)
                 );
```

my requirement is to return a refcursor with two columns

```
1. Demo_id 
2. Status column
```

Which will be derived as follows:

```
if created_date = mod_date then "New" else "Updated" .
```

So I have written my code as :

```
select demo_id ,case when created_date=mod_date then "New" else "update" end from demo;
```

but somehow even though the dates are same including the timecomponent My status value is always showing updated. I am using SQL developer to run my queries and have also modified the nls_date_format to be DD/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:SS.
Also mod_date will be storing systimestamp.

Comment: Can you try using - `case when TO_DATE(created_date) = TO_DATE(mod_date) then "New" else "update" end`

Comment: That relies on implicit conversion of the timestamp to a string, which means the `nls_timestamp_format` and `nls_date_format` would both have to be the same (and both have second precision) - so it would be safer to at least do explicit conversion and provide both format masks. There isn't any point doing `to_date(created_date)` though - even with a full format mask (and explicit conversion) or NLS setting it will end up as the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a date, which has a second precision, with a timestamp, which has fractional-second precision.

If `created_date` is taken from sysdate and `mod_date` is taken from systimestamp then you could be comparing something like `2022-08-06 23:36:58` with `2022-08-06 23:36:58.373657`. Those are not the same.

The data type comparison and [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-82C9B166-5850-48F5-B3ED-BB82B3631407) rules mean that the date value is implicitly converted to a timestamp, but that just means it's now comparing `2022-08-06 23:36:58.000000` with `2022-08-06 23:36:58.373657`. Those are still not the same.

As you can't add precision to the date, you will have to remove precision from the timestamp, which you can do by casting it to that data type:

```
case when created_date = cast(mod_date as date) then 'New' else 'Updated' end as status
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=28986a35dbd47e6960b0e41c5844b170)

However, if the row is modified during the same second it was created - e.g. from the example used before, if `mod_date` is set to `2022-08-06 23:36:58.999999` - then that won't be seen as an update, since once the precision is reduced the original and updated `mod_date` are identical, and both the same as `created_date`.

That might not be an issue for you, but it would still be simpler if you made `created_date` a timestamp as well, and set that with `systimestamp` too.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for providing the solution. I tried and it works. Thanks a lot for it.I  relatively new to Oracle but this solution is a life saver for me.

Comment: @SurbhiSharma you can mark the answer as correct if it answers your question.